# Retrieving claims from a controller - how?

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

I'm told that if I want to grab a claim within a controller I can do something like:

```
IClaimsIdentity u = (IClaimsIdentity) this.HttpContext.User.Identity;
var ni = u.Claims.First(x => x.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

however, this violates the separation between views and controllers.  the controller may be called in a context where there is no `HttpContext` - so what is the proper way to do it?

TIA - ekkis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the `HttpContext` and use the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property of the controller directly:

```
var u = (IClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;
```